# Remove the 64bit option from ext4 filesystem

Tags: linux, ext4

I have a 50GB ext4 FS that was mistakenly created with the 64bit extension. I'd like to know the extension can now be removed or if it is necessary to start from scratch.

[This link](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/resize2fs.8.html) suggests that it may be done with resize2fs, but the mentioned -s flag is not available on any machine I have access to (up to FC22)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This task can only be done with the newer (> 1.42.12) resize2fs releases.